# Unable to launch steam/tf2 using nouveau

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, steam, opengl, nouveau

Trying to use nouveau driver isntead of the nvidia driver cause of poor performance, but I am unable to launch steam to use the dedicated card.

Launching as `env DRI_PRIME=1 steam steam://rungameid/440`

getting

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465948400)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Launching tf2 seperately also fails,. `DRI_PRIME=1 ~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Team\ Fortress\ 2/hl2.sh` gives me,

```
SDL video target is 'x11'
SDL video target is 'x11'
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_framebuffer_object.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_APPLE_fence.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_NV_fence.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_sync.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_draw_buffers2.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_bindable_uniform.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_APPLE_flush_buffer_range.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_map_buffer_range.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_occlusion_query.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_APPLE_texture_range.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_APPLE_client_storage.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_uniform_buffer.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_framebuffer_object.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_GREMEDY_string_marker.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_debug_output.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_direct_state_access.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_NV_bindless_texture.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_AMD_pinned_memory.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_ATI_meminfo.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_buffer_storage.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear.
OpenGL: Gallium 0.4 on NVD7 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0 (3.0.0)
GL_NV_bindless_texture: DISABLED
GL_AMD_pinned_memory: DISABLED
GL_ARB_buffer_storage: AVAILABLE
GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode: AVAILABLE
AppFramework : Unable to load module vguimatsurface.so!
Unable to load interface VGUI_Surface030 from vguimatsurface.so
```

`glxgears` works. What do I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give This a shot.

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' steam
```

Hope it helps.

Steam has its own built in Runtime Library. You can find more information on it [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Steam/Troubleshooting#Steam_runtime_issues)

Ironically this works with Ubuntu as well.

Comment: I don't get it ...

Comment: ` LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DRI_PRIME=1 steam` to use it with dedicated GPU

Answer (score -1):

#### How to: (KDE Linux 64-bit)

On a clean or freshly installed and fully updated operating system. (Make sure the non-free repository is enabled).  Reboot at least once after updating. Download a Nvidia driver run file that suits your video card from Nvidia.com. Make sure you copy the run file into your `/home/your-username` directory. Do not copy it into documents or downloads. That makes it more difficult for you.

Stop using the Nouveau driver by using the "Configure Video Card" to enable the VESA video driver. *Do not* remove Nouveau or you will upset shared libraries. After installing VESA with the low resolution.

From here on I suggest you either write the following commands on a piece of paper or bookmark this page on your phone.

1. Open a terminal.
2. As root, enter `init 3` (init 3  =  Network is present, multitasking is present but without a GUI) Nvidia will never install in a graphical user interface. Now you panic as you only have black screen waiting for your input.
3. Enter root.
4. Enter your password.
5. Enter `cd /home/yourname` (This places you looking at your home directory).
6. Enter `ls` (This shows you what files are there in your home directory; complete with the name of the nvidia.run file that you need for the next step.)
7. Enter `sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-xxx.xx.run` (Type exactly what Nvidia name `ls` shows you.)
8. Answer all questions with yes by using the left or right keys and Enter key to accept.

   The .run file is a self-extracting archive. When executed, it extracts the contents of the archive and runs the contained nvidia-installer utility, which provides an interactive interface to walk you through the installation.
9. After Nvidia installer finishes the init 3 screen returns to your root command. Enter `reboot`

Now you have successfully installed the proprietary Nvidia driver with all of the required dependencies. You will notice that it also rewrites the grub2 to stop using Nouveau.

Comment: "Nvidia will never install in a graphical user interface" is not strictly true. Ubuntu has  a program that not only installs the Nvidia driver from a graphical user interface, but it also automatically scans your system and installs the correct proprietary Nvidia graphics driver and not only installs the required dependencies, but installs the recommended packages as well. It also handles everything related to the open source Nouveau driver automatically without uninstalling any Nouveau packages.